# Generate table in hubot brain and insert values

Tags: node.js, redis, hubot

I'm trying to make a table of values inside hubot and he pass it's values to redis-brain.coffee but i just know a way: robot.brain.get("blablabla").
This will get a string from redis-brain and i need some kind of table.

How I'll use it:
At first call of this function, hubot will load the full database to the memory, then, if there's

```
  robot.catchAll (msg) ->
if not quiet
  text = msg.message.text
  ector.setUser msg.message.user.name
  if not loaded_brain
    ector_brain = robot.brain.get('ector_brain') #need to be some type of table - In mysql should be like a select
    ector.addEntry ector_brain
    loaded_brain = true
  else
    ector.addEntry text
    ector_brain = ector_brain+text #this line should insert the value of text inside ector_brain table. -- In mysql shoud be like an insert into
  ector.linkNodesToLastSentence previousResponseNodes
  response = ector.generateResponse()
  previousResponseNodes = response.nodes
  msg.reply response.sentence
```

So, how do I create a table in redis from hubot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robot.brain.get` and `robot.brain.set` operates with JSON objects, not only strings. Just place an object with your data structure of choice in the brain and get it back when necessary.